# DataAnnotations Displayname("Some thing here") and using italics, possible?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, data-annotations

As the title suggests i have:

```
DisplayName("This is the display name")
int Id {get;set;}
```

And i would like to set a part of this name in italics.

```
DisplayName("This is the <i>display name</i>")
int Id {get;set;}
```

But this is getting sanitized and the HTML is not getting used. Is there a way round this?

I can't put the italics on the view itself as i only want a part of the display name italicized.

Cheers,
Kohan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to create your own **[Custom Template](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html)**. Then you have the full control over the HTML being rendered.